# Transactional Replication not copying the user table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

I have configured the Transaction Replication between SQL Server A and B ( A being the publisher and distributor) and B as a Subscriber. I do see that the subscriber job has been created under Local subscription in SQL serve B, and all of the system tables, views, stored proc has been copied but non of the User table has been copied? 
Can you guide me how to resolve this issue?

SQL server version: 2008R2

Comment: Probably better asked at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you see the subscription in replication monitor? If you can, navigate to the agents tab for the subscription and attempt to start the snapshot agent, this should perform an initial sync (presuming everything is set up correctly). If not, can you confirm you have added all of the user tables to the publication (right click the publication in the server explorer and view properties > articles). Add the user tables here if not (and then perform the snapshot above).

Comment: As Jamie said, either start the agent via repl monitor or just right click the publication and reinitialize it (assuming you have actually added the right articles to the publication)

Comment: I see that the User tables has been added correctly. But i saw this error message at the replication mirror "The process could not read file 'F:\Program Files\MS SQL SERVER\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ReplData\unc\' due to OS error 21. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20024)

Answer (score 1):

Posting as answer for longevity! Your initial issue was that the publication wasn't intitialised so you have to set off an initial snapshot. Navigate to the replication monitor > agents tab and right click > start the agent:

[image]

Your second issue is that you seem to have specified a path for the replication that isn't shared or accessible. if you right click the publication and click properties, then find the snapshot page. Set the snapshot location folder to be a shared folder \\ServerName\Sharename and share the actual folder. This means that the snapshot can be read by the mirror / subscriber. You will need to re-run the snapshot above.